# How do I access information in Windows Device Manager in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, usb

How do I import Device Manager-like details of devices in my C++ code?

I have tried Setupapi routines, but these do not give me Device Manager-like details of the device property value.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14469/Simple-Device-Manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something called Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) can be used for this.

Comment: thanks Robinson your answer leads me to this links https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390418(v=vs.85).aspx     and after little changes that code works