# How to check the version of the available USB ports?

Tags: c++, usb, libusb

I need to check, from a C++ program, which version of USB port is available on the system the program is running on.
For now I need it on Windows, but Linux will be next.

Is there a function as simple as: `int GetUsbVersion()`?

I would not need anything as complex as [libusb](http://libusb.info/), but just in case which of its functions should I use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160635/how-to-determine-usb-port-version-on-windows

Comment: @sailfish009: There they propose USBView, which is a complete GUI application. I am looking for a low level function to call from a C++ program.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/usb/usbview in the link, there is a function.

Answer (score 1):

in linux it is `lsusb`  | grep ... or directly with `libusb` commands (in the `libusb__device__descriptor` the field `bcdUSB` )

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 04f2:b1d8 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

the `2.0, 1.1 , ...` is the version of the root hub. if there is 2.0 or 3.0 root hub then there is also and 1.1 (and/or 2.0) for backwards compatibility

http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/structlibusb__device__descriptor.html
https://itsfoss.com/find-usb-3-port-linux/

in windows this is more difficult because windows provides very bad access to lower-level USB functions. Graphically this can be done by determining the version of the USB host controller in the `Device Manager` under `Universal Serial Bus controllers`, see https://kb.iu.edu/d/aout

USB 1.1 is `open (OHCI)`, USB 2.0 is `enhanced (EHCI)` USB 3.0 is `extensible (xHCI)` host controller interface

you can access informations of the Device Manager from C++ using WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation). For finding out what USB protocol versions are used you have to query the USB root hubs ( `Win32_USBHub class` ), see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394506(v=vs.85).aspx

```
[Dynamic, Provider("CIMWin32a"), UUID("{52E56374-B17E-41DC-00EC-FC3E6E8D8783}"), AMENDMENT]
class Win32_USBHub : CIM_USBHub
{
  uint16   Availability;
  string   Caption;
  uint8    ClassCode;
  boolean  ConfigManagerUserConfig;
  string   CreationClassName;
  uint8    CurrentAlternateSettings[];
  uint8    CurrentConfigValue;
  string   Description;
  boolean  ErrorCleared;
  string   ErrorDescription;
  boolean  GangSwitched;
  datetime InstallDate;
  uint32   LastErrorCode;
  uint8    NumberOfConfigs;
  uint8    NumberOfPorts;
  string   PNPDeviceID;
  uint16   PowerManagementCapabilities[];
  boolean  PowerManagementSupported;
  uint8    ProtocolCode;
  string   Status;
  uint16   StatusInfo;
  uint8    SubclassCode;
  string   SystemCreationClassName;
  string   SystemName;
  uint16   USBVersion;   <------------------
  uint32   ConfigManagerErrorCode;
  string   DeviceID;
  string   Name;
};
```

- **https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394506(v=vs.85).aspx**
- **http://www.powertheshell.com/reference/wmireference/root/cimv2/win32_usbhub/**
- https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/5e2b2a59-84ec-4df2-a61d-70a6bf739578 - Script USB List Hub Information
- **https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2007/02/24/displaying-usb-devices-using-wmi/**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449417(v=winembedded.82).aspx

[How do I access information in Windows Device Manager in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231470/how-to-access-information-in-windows-device-manager-in-c)